# How to read network interface configuration in VxWorks

Tags: networking, kernel-module, vxworks

I can inspect the address from the vxworks shell using the ifconfig shell command.

I would like to perform the equivalent function programmatically, in a downloadable kernel module (DKM).

How can I determine the IP address of the interface "gem0", in my DKM?

In the VxWorks developer documentation, I see the function ifAddrGet() in ifLib.h, which seems to do exactly what I want. However, this function does not seem to be available to me:

```
C interp: unknown symbol name 'ifAddrGet'
```

Is the inclusion of this library kernel dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a DKM you should be able to use this command. Have you tried to use `ifconfig("gem0 something...");` instead, for testing if you can access the networksettings in general? Perhaps make shure that you are able to use this commands (installed packages) in your "Kernel Configuration".

Comment: I didn't consider this a reasonable solution, because the output goes to STD_OUT. It might work, if I can redirect the output to somewhere, other than the filesystem.

Comment: at least "ifconfig" returns OK or ERROR.But is it working? If yes, "ifAddrGet( )" should work too.

Comment: by the way, you wrote "ifGetAddr()" instead of "ifAddrGet( )" - maybe that was your problem in the first place

Comment: The problem for me is that ifLib doesn't seem to be accessible for me. I cant call anything in there.

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729861/how-to-save-the-output-of-ifconfig-command-into-a-buffer ... redirects the console to a named pipe, which is char buffer. works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case of primary address,

```
-> myBuf = malloc(128)
myBuf = 0x833d8e8: value = 301883024 = 0x11fe5e90
-> ifAddrGet "qfec0", myBuf
value = 0 = 0x0
-> puts myBuf
192.168.1.9
value = 10 = 0xa
-> free myBuf
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Comment: I have ifconfig, but do not have ifAddGet.=>  C interp: unknown symbol name 'ifAddrGet'